# wso2 governance registry - dependencies and associations

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I would like to know more about the difference between dependencies and associations in WSO2 governance registry.
Is there any tutorial presenting a relevant use case?

To investigate, I created two resources with a dependency and then an association between them. Then I updated/deleted one of the resources but I wasn't warned that I broke a link.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An association can be created from any resource (or collection) on the registry to another resource (or collection) on the registry or an external resource which can be referred to by a URL. While the source should be a resource existing on the registry, the destination resource can be anything for which a URL can be given. Association has a type associated.

eg: Document A that confirms to a standard B, 
You can create an association between those two by stating A "confirms to" B, where association name is "confirms to".

Dependency is a specialization of associations, which states that a resource has a dependency on another resource.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Thilini